# moving (user input) files to another location

Tags: command-line, bash, trash, mv

I'm totally new to Linux and trying to do a simple move with user input like this:

```
echo "where do you want to move the file to?"
read location
mv ~/my-applications/bin/trash/* $location
```

This works great, however, I wish to move a specified file specified by user input.  For example, I wish to move `test` from trash but there is another file called `dontmoveme`. My script moves everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the file by adding another `read`:

```
echo "what do you want to move?"
read file
echo "where do you want to put it?"
read location
mv -v -- "$file" "$location"
```

If the script is just to move things from a particular location then you can of course give the path...

```
mv -v -- ~/my-applications/bin/trash/"$file" "$location"
```

I added `-v` so `mv` will tell you what it is doing - remove if preferred. I also added `--` to tell `mv` not to interpret any following input as options, just to avoid any weird behaviour if someone enters any text beginning with `-`

Comment: Thank You. That does exactly what I was asking for..your a Star :)